# PHP equivalent of JAVAs HexUtils.bytesToHex()

Tags: java, php, character-encoding

I need to encode a string in md5 and then it's bytes to 2 chars hex encoding.

I've got this short JAVA snippets and need to convert it into PHP.

```
  // Condensed the message and do MD5
  try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] data = cleartext.getBytes(ENCODING);
    md.update(data);
    byte[] digestedByteArray = md.digest();
    // Convert digested bytes to 2 chars Hex Encoding
    md5String = HexUtils.bytesToHex(digestedByteArray);

  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ns) {
    ns.printStackTrace();
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this in PHP. `ENCODING` is `UTF-8`

What I have in PHP is

```
$md5String = md5($clearText);
$hexString = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($md5String); $i++) {
  $hexString .= dechex(ord($md5String[$i]));
}
```

But the output is different, so I think I'm failing on the hex conversion.

So what's the proper port of this JAVA snippet to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of [`md5`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is already a hex-encoded string, so there is nothing else you need to do (as long as you don't set the optional second parameter to `true`).

```
$hexString = md5($clearText);
```